# Could not parse the remainder: '${id}' from '${id}'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

Hi there I am working on a blogpage using django rest framework api system.
I am trying to set the url id using javascript DOM but don't know where it all go wrong

my javascript code:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getdata')
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(data => {
                   ul = document.getElementById('my-list');
                   ul.innerHTML = '';
                   data.forEach(element => {
                       const list = document.createElement('div')
                       id = element.id
                       list.innerHTML = `
                       <h1 class='text-uppercase' >${element.title}</h1>
                       <hr>
                       <h5>@${element.author}</h5>
                       <div>${element.content} </div>
                       <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteitem(${element.id})">delete</button>
                       <a href="{% url 'editpost' ${id} %}" class="btn btn-info"></a>
                       `;
                       list.classList.add('card');
                       list.classList.add('card-body');
                       list.classList.add('mb-2');
                       ul.appendChild(list);
                       console.log(element.title)
                   });
               })
```

if you need more informations please ask

I have try it to use {{}} and {} and just raw id it didn't work

Edit:
nvm I fixed it using direct URL link
code: `<a href="/editpost/${id}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed backend code with frontend code. The backend code obviously cannot access the frontend JS runtime. You have to store the URL fragment in the JS variable then assemble the final URL at the frontend:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getdata')
           .then(response => response.json())
           .then(data => {
               ul = document.getElementById('my-list');
               ul.innerHTML = '';
               const url_prefix = '{% url "editpost" %}';
               data.forEach(element => {
                   const list = document.createElement('div')
                   id = element.id                       
                   list.innerHTML = `
                   <h1 class='text-uppercase' >${element.title}</h1>
                   <hr>
                   <h5>@${element.author}</h5>
                   <div>${element.content} </div>
                   <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteitem(${element.id})">delete</button>
                   <a href="${url_prefix}${id}" class="btn btn-info"></a>
                   `;
                   list.classList.add('card');
                   list.classList.add('card-body');
                   list.classList.add('mb-2');
                   ul.appendChild(list);
                   console.log(element.title)
               });
           })
```

Make sure that you can reverse `editpost` endpoint without the argument (which will be determined at the frontend).